# Pandas - apply absolute value to column

Tags: python, pandas

The following:

```
record = record.loc[(record['Media_Casa'].abs() > 0.5)
                   &(record['Media_Fora'].abs() > 0.5)]
```

Throws the following error:

```
    record = record.loc[(record['Media_Casa'].abs() > 0.5)
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'abs'", 'occurred at index 2')
```

How do I get the absolute values for all values in this?

Comment: What is `print(type(record))`?

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: @ALollz `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Well that's your problem. Since `record` is a 1D Series selection with `[]` will return a value as it slices the Index. (can return a Series if index is duplicated) floats don't have the `.abs` attribute so you would need `np.abs(record['Media_Casa'])` for instance, but this selection seems weird. as it can never equate to True...

Answer (score 0):

It is a multi-index series with one indexing being `Media_Casa` and another being `Media_Fora`. A cleaner way to do what you want is by converting it into a dataframe.

```
record = pd.Series({
    'Media_Casa': [1,0.5,1,0.4],
    'Media_Fora': [1,0.4,0.5,.4],
})

print (record.index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Media_Casa' : record['Media_Casa'], 'Media_Fora' :record['Media_Fora']})
df.loc[(df['Media_Casa'].abs() > 0.5)
                   &(df['Media_Fora'].abs() > 0.5)]
```

Output:

```
Index(['Media_Casa', 'Media_Fora'], dtype='object')
   Media_Casa   Media_Fora
0   1.0         1.0
```